# Are there any LTL to _non_ deterministic Rabin automaton translators?

Tags: automata, reference-request, simulation, linear-temporal-logic

I know of two translators LTL -> deterministic Rabin automaton:

- [Rabinizer3](https://rabinizer.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/)
- [ltl2dstar](http://ltl2dstar.de/)

They produce *deterministic* automata, which can be much larger than their possible non-deterministic variants. Is there a translator LTL -> *non* deterministic Rabin?

(my synthesis tool could handle *small non-det* Rabin automata but not large though det ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily translate LTL to non-deterministic Buchi automata, which can be thought of as a simple fragment of Rabin automata (although they are equally expressive).
I don't think any tool would actually output the acceptance condition described as a Rabin condition, but this is very easy to deduce from the Buchi states.

An example of an online tool to do this conversion is:
http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/

But I'm sure there are many others, as the construction is relatively simple.

Comment: yes, we can.. But do you mean that there is no "size" benefit in using non-det Rabin automata over non-det Buchi automata for LTL formulas? (i.e., for any LTL formula, the size of minimal non-det Rabin automaton equals to the size of minimal non-det Buchi?) (where size is the number of states)

Comment: It is true that Rabin automata may be more succinct than Buchi automata, even for nondeterministic ones. However, the lower bound in the blowup is the same. In addition, I don't think there is a translation from LTL to non-det Rabin that will give you significantly smaller automata (no more than a polynomial factor, I think).

Comment: @Ayrat I am not sure whether the tool called [GOAL](http://goal.im.ntu.edu.tw/wiki/doku.php#download) satisfies the OP's requirement. (Personally, I think it is a very wonderful tool with a long-term goal "to handle all the common variants of omega-automata and the logics that are expressively equivalent to these automata".  )